# How long CAN account recovery take?

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I don't know if anyone has had a similar situation going on with their account recovery if you ever tried to use this Apple feature but this is what happened:

I was locked out of my Apple ID account because I had been hacked. Because of this, I changed my passwords numerous times, even my Apple ID for safety measures and for some reason I got a notification that someone from New York (I live in Missouri) was trying to access my account, thanks to two-step authorization, I declined the access **BUT** then a few days later my Apple ID said it needed me to put my password into my iPad for security purposes and my password didn't work! I write all my passwords down in a secure place and somehow my password had been changed!! I quickly tried account recovery and it said it would take a few days for Apple to send me a text message on my phone of instructions on how to fix the issue and I have yet to receive the message (it has been exactly 2 weeks and 3 days) I called Apple Support and they said all I can do is wait, because sometimes it does take more than 10 days.

Well now my iPad keeps sending me a notification on my screen EVERY 20 SECONDS saying "APPLE ID VERIFICATION, enter password" but I can't because I'm still locked out of my Apple ID and I don't know the password. I understand waiting more than 10 days, but this is ridiculous. I called Apple Support again and all they had to say was "I'm sorry but we can't help you. It does take more than 10 days sometimes for account recovery to activate." SERIOUSLY?! I also can't go to an Apple Store for help because I'm currently on vacation out of country and there is not one near by and I won't be home for another 3 weeks, and I can't wait that long since I use my iPad for work and almost everything else.

Does anyone have any information that could help me with my issue? Any information at all. Please. I am begging!

Comment: Have you simply tried going to iforgot.apple.com and enter your Apple ID? You can choose to have the reset sent to your email on account, or answer security questions..

Comment: Customer support timing is really up to the vendor. Since account recovery could be rejected, it could take forever.